# Conditional rendering with Solana Wallet Adapter & NextJS

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, react, nextjs

I was wondering whether this was a **safe way** to render **certain elements** only for **specific pubkeys** when connected through **Solana wallet adapter** in Nextjs.
This code returns an < AdminPanel /> when we are logged in with one of the pubkeys in adminList[].

```
import { useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
    
const { publicKey } = useWallet();       
if (publicKey.toBase58() === adminList[1].publickey)
        ) {
            return ( <AdminPanel /> ); }
else {
return ( <UserPanel /> ) ; }
```

I realize I have to protect my api routes as well when fetching data, but would it be possible for someone with bad intentions to **access the AdminPanel element** without being **logged in** with one of the **pubkeys in the adminList[]** array?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Backend API Protection should be there for sure and better bring in the AdminList from the backend and then validate. I would suggest to make the publickey validation more secure better sign a message before doing this check so that the platform get's 100% sure that its a legit address.

Comment: Thank you! The adminList does come from the backend. I will look into backend API protection & message signing!  If you have any suggestions for auth libraries to go with sol wallet adapter, please let me know.  I'm using TRPC & Vercel as back-end.  Thanks again!

Comment: awesome i have heard good things about TRPC will try it out soon, what type of auth are you looking for is it like phantom,solflare and all the wallets in solana or do you mean something else by auth

Comment: I'm wondering whether I can be sure that that specific user is logged in on Solana with that Phantom/other Sol wallets if I run ` if (connected && publicKey === pubkeyfromdb )  ` after ` const { publicKey, connected } = useWallet(); ` Or do I need to sign a message everytime I grant someone access to my database based on {publicKey && connected} ? I think I will run nextauth in parallel as backend API Protection, signing in & out as connected becomes true or false.  I'm new to Solana so open to suggestions! 

Comment: Sounds Good but just makes sure to remove the DB access on refresh or on wallet change/reconnect